# Is it possible to extract page_location from this JSON string in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, json, events, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this JSON column and I need to extract the string_value for key: page_location into its own column. I must use Snowflake SQL.

```
[
  {
    "key": "page_title",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "Welcome"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "version",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "567"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "firebase_conversion",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "0"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "session_engaged",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "0"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "container_id",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "GTM-PHSFA"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "ga_session_number",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "210"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "engaged_session_event",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "content_group",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "Homepage"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "entrances",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "hostname",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "www.homepage.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "user_agent",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12)"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "ga_session_id",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "1194643792"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "page_location",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "https://www.examplehomepage.com/"
    }
  }
]
```

I feel like I have tried everything! Thank you for the help.

Comment: On the command line: `jq '.[] | select (.key=="page_location").value.string_value' < example_data.json`

Answer (score 1):

```
with data(json) as (
    select parse_json('[
  {
    "key": "page_title",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "Welcome"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "version",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "567"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "firebase_conversion",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "0"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "session_engaged",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "0"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "container_id",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "GTM-PHSFA"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "ga_session_number",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "210"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "engaged_session_event",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "content_group",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "Homepage"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "entrances",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "hostname",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "www.homepage.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "user_agent",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12)"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "ga_session_id",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "1194643792"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "page_location",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "https://www.examplehomepage.com/"
    }
  }
]')
)
select 
    f.value:value as here_you_go
from data as d,
table(flatten(input=>d.json)) as f
where f.value:key = 'page_location';
```

[image]

which if the sample input data is reduced to something more correct sized:

```
with data(json) as (
    select parse_json('[
  {
    "key": "ga_session_id",
    "value": {
      "int_value": "1194643792"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "page_location",
    "value": {
      "string_value": "https://www.examplehomepage.com/"
    }
  }
]')
)
```

then the WHERE clause can be dropped:

```
select 
    *
from data as d,
table(flatten(input=>d.json)) as f
--where f.value:key = 'page_location'
;
```

[image]

then we can see how to SELECT what we want, and tell the DB what we do not want, and we are all the ways back at the begining.

```
select 
    f.value:value as here_you_go
from data as d,
table(flatten(input=>d.json)) as f
where f.value:key = 'page_location';
```